# Dynamically Change Y Axis Size Based on Slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a spreadsheet that has information on credit card applications. In Power BI, I have created calculations to calculate the number of applications (COUNT), and other calculated measures that give me the number of applications based on different filters (CALCULATE).

I then created a slicer that slices the data based on type of card. So say I have a line chart that shows the number of applications for males and females, I can then use the slicer to select different cards.

The trouble I'm running into, is that some cards have a lot more applicants than another. This can be difficult for display, as I set certain Y Axis ranges for the data labels to be clear. So if I have one line chart that the minimum is 100 and max is 500 for one card, if I click on another card in the slicer, then the Y axis size is still 100 - 500, which isn't great if another card  in the slicer pane only has 50 applicants.

Does anyone know of a creative way to dynamically change the Y Axis sizes, based on a slicer selection?

Comment: don't set the y axis min and max manually. Leave it up to Power BI, then it will adjust the required range automatically.